# How to list Tags using get_tags in an html table?

Tags: tags, html, table

Any suggestions on the simplest way to display tags using get_tags in an html table (4 columns across) ?

Example: 

Tag 1 |  Tag2  | Tag 3 | Tag 4 

Tag 5 | Tag 6  | Tag 7 | Tag 8

I'm using the following code to display tags, I found it in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags).:

```
    $tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ($tags as $tag){
    $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and it works well. I am using `array_chunk`, but I'm also adding a check to see if a chunk has less than 4 values (as you want 4 columns), then just add a blank `<td>`, which will avoid the mark up from breaking.

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags(array('hide_empty' => false));
$tag_groups = array_chunk($tags, 4);
$t = '<table>';
foreach($tag_groups as $tag_single)
{   
    $t .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++)
    {
        if(isset($tag_single[$i]) && !empty($tag_single[$i]))
        {
            $tag_link = get_tag_link($tag_single[$i]->term_id);
            $t .= "<td><a href='".$tag_link."' title='".$tag_single[$i]->name."'>".$tag_single[$i]->name."</a></td>";
        }
        else
        {
            $t .= "<td></td>";
        }
    }
    $t .= '</tr>';
}

echo $t .= "</table>";
?>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well your code does not have any HTML tables but I will assume you still want tables and not DIV's.

The best way ( I think) is to use `array_chunk` , your example has 4 columns so something along the lines of (not tested);

```
<?php $tags = get_tags(); ?>

 <table>
   <?php foreach (array_chunk($tags, 4) as $row) {  ?>  <!-- 4 chunks-->
    <tr>
     <?php foreach ($row as $value) { ?>
      <td><?php echo $value; ?></td> <!-- or your $tag_link-->
     <?php } ?>
    </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```